# How to solve 'emacs emms player list is empty'

Tags: emacs

I was trying to use emacs emms to play music.
I loaded the playlist. And chose a song. Pressed enter to play it.
But emms showed a message in minibuf: emms-player-list empty

What should I do?

emms is installed. M-x package-install RET emms.
Should I install something else?

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing happened to me.

It's because I use use-package and misconfigured it (`defer` option to `t` and code not loaded after `emms` invocation).

This is a working use-package declaration :

```lisp
    (use-package emms-setup
      :ensure nil
      :init
      (add-hook 'emms-player-started-hook 'emms-show)
      :config
      (setq emms-show-format "Playing: %s")
      (emms-all)
      (emms-default-players)
      (setq emms-source-file-default-directory "~/Musique/")
      )
```

Without use-package, referring to the [quickstart guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/#Quickstart-Guide), a simple

```lisp
(require 'emms-setup)
(emms-all)
(emms-default-players)
```

should get you rocking !